# Change CCAnimation, but retain frame index

Tags: cocos2d-x

Unit in my game can move in 8 directions (N, NE, E, SE etc.). When unit change direction I want CCAnimate to retain animation frame (change only CCAnimation), to avoid animation jump if unit change facing in mid-step. My current code:

```
pSprite->stopAllActions();
CCAnimate* animate = CCAnimate::create((*currentAnimation)[(int)facing]);
CCRepeatForever* action = CCRepeatForever::create( animate );
pSprite->runAction( action );
```

Where currentAnimation is vector containing array of CCSpriteFrame. How I can achive it?
I'm using cocos2d-x 2.2

Answer (score 3):

CCAnimate has protected member variable m_nNextFrame, that contains the index to the current animation frame. You could try creating a class that extends CCAnimate and creating a public setter / getter functions to set that index to desired one, before starting the animation.